# How to insert key value from one array of object to another array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have below 2 array of object and I wanted to copy one key value pair from one array object to another one. I have try below method but it is not working.

```
const array1 = [{id: 'A123', state: 'Test'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'A123', value: 'Test Value'}];
```

Expected output

```
[{id: 'A123', state: 'Test', value: 'Test Value'}];
```

I have try the below method but it is not working

```
 const arraVal = array1.map((item, i) => ({
     ...item,
      value: array2[i].value,
     }));
```

Can you also let me know how we can do it based on id that present in both array , so that i can get below expected ouptut

```
[{id: 'A123', state: 'Test', value: 'Test Value'}];
```

Comment: How is your attempt _"not working"_? Looks like it works when I run it

Comment: Ah, I know. I will use some fancy array functions `Object.values(Object.groupBy([...array1, ...array2], ({ id }) => id)).map(e => e.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, ...cur })))`

Comment: @HaoWu that's pretty neat, you should add an answer to the duplicate

Comment: I think `Object.groupBy` [hasn't been widely supported yet](https://caniuse.com/?search=object.groupby). So it is better to not be used on production environments. But it may worth to try in the future.